# How to transform a list into a CSV text file with headers and the corresponding values?

Tags: list, csv, dictionary, ansible

I have a variable, data_list, but it ends up all in a single row, spread over multiple cells in the CSV text file:

```
[{"FirstName": "Peter", "AliasName": "", "Code": "#3091", "DateofSubmission": "14/5/2023", "Description": "NIL", "path": "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"}, {"FirstName": "Sam", "AliasName": "", "Code": "#3092", "DateofSubmission": "2/5/2023", "Description": "NIL", "path": "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"}, {"FirstName": "Judy", "AliasName": "", "Code": "#3093", "DateofSubmission": "10/5/2023", "Description": "NIL","path": "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"}]
```

Playbook version debug data_list:

```
    - debug:
        var: data_list
```

```
    "data_list": [
        {
            "AliasName": "",
            "Code": "#3091",
            "DateofSubmission": "14/5/2023",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": "Peter",
            "path": "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local" 
        },
        {
            "AliasName": "",
            "Code": "#3092",
            "DateofSubmission": "2/5/2023",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": "Sam",
            "path": "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
        },
        {
            "AliasName": "",
            "Code": "#3093",
            "DateofSubmission": "10/5/2023",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": "Judy",
            "path": "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local" 
        }
    ]
}
```

What code would I need in order to transform the data_list into a CSV file with headers and their corresponding values as below?

```
FirstName , Alias Name , Code, Date of Submission, Description, path  
Peter,,#3091,14/5/2023,NIL,"OU=fulltime,OU=TestOU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
Sam,,#3092,2/5/2023,2/5/2023,NIL,"OU=parttime,OU=TestOU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
Judy,,#3093,10/5/2023,NIL,"OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
```

---

Update (Comment by Blitzden)

This is what I got when I debug the template:

```
FirstName,Alias Name,Code,Date of Submission,Description,path\n
Peter,,#3091,14/5/2023,NIL,\"OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local\"
Sam,,#3092,2/5/2023,NIL,\"OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local\"
Judy,,#3093,10/5/2023,NIL,\"OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local\"\n
```

Comment: The missing newlines `\n` are the result of your decision to ignore the proper [formatting](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#whitespace-control) of the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the conversion

```yaml
  label:
    FirstName: FirstName
    Alias Name: AliasName
    Code: Code
    Date of Submission: DateofSubmission
    Description: Description
    path: path
```

- The template is rather simple when you use another delimiter than comma ','

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ label.keys()|join(delimiter) }}
          {% set _keys=label.values()|list %}
          {% for data in data_list %}
          {{ _keys|map('extract', data)|join(delimiter) }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        delimiter: ';'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    FirstName;Alias Name;Code;Date of Submission;Description;path
    Peter;;#3091;14/5/2023;NIL;OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local
    Sam;;#3092;2/5/2023;NIL;OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local
    Judy;;#3093;10/5/2023;NIL;OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local
```

- You have to quote the attribute *path* if you use the comma ',' as the delimiter. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ label.keys()|join(delimiter) }}
          {% set _keys=label.values()|list %}
          {% for data in data_list %}
          {% for k in _keys %}
          {% if k in quote_list %}
          "{{ data[k] }}"{% if not loop.last %}{{ delimiter }}{% endif %}
          {% else %}
          {{ data[k] }}{% if not loop.last %}{{ delimiter }}{% endif %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        delimiter: ','
        quote_list: [path]
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    FirstName,Alias Name,Code,Date of Submission,Description,path
    Peter,,#3091,14/5/2023,NIL,"OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
    Sam,,#3092,2/5/2023,NIL,"OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
    Judy,,#3093,10/5/2023,NIL,"OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
```

- Write the CSV data to a file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.csv
        content: |
          {{ label.keys()|join(delimiter) }}
          {% set _keys=label.values()|list %}
          {% for data in data_list %}
          {% for k in _keys %}
          {% if k in quote_list %}
          "{{ data[k] }}"{% if not loop.last %}{{ delimiter }}{% endif %}
          {% else %}
          {{ data[k] }}{% if not loop.last %}{{ delimiter }}{% endif %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        delimiter: ','
        quote_list: [path]
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.csv
FirstName,Alias Name,Code,Date of Submission,Description,path
Peter,,#3091,14/5/2023,NIL,"OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
Sam,,#3092,2/5/2023,NIL,"OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
Judy,,#3093,10/5/2023,NIL,"OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    data_list:
      - AliasName: ''
        Code: '#3091'
        DateofSubmission: 14/5/2023
        Description: NIL
        FirstName: Peter
        path: OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local
      - AliasName: ''
        Code: '#3092'
        DateofSubmission: 2/5/2023
        Description: NIL
        FirstName: Sam
        path: OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local
      - AliasName: ''
        Code: '#3093'
        DateofSubmission: 10/5/2023
        Description: NIL
        FirstName: Judy
        path: OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local

    label:
      FirstName: FirstName
      Alias Name: AliasName
      Code: Code
      Date of Submission: DateofSubmission
      Description: Description
      path: path

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ label.keys()|join(delimiter) }}
          {% set _keys=label.values()|list %}
          {% for data in data_list %}
          {{ _keys|map('extract', data)|join(delimiter) }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        delimiter: ';'

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ label.keys()|join(delimiter) }}
          {% set _keys=label.values()|list %}
          {% for data in data_list %}
          {% for k in _keys %}
          {% if k in quote_list %}
          "{{ data[k] }}"{% if not loop.last %}{{ delimiter }}{% endif %}
          {% else %}
          {{ data[k] }}{% if not loop.last %}{{ delimiter }}{% endif %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        delimiter: ','
        quote_list: [path]
        
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.csv
        content: |
          {{ label.keys()|join(delimiter) }}
          {% set _keys=label.values()|list %}
          {% for data in data_list %}
          {% for k in _keys %}
          {% if k in quote_list %}
          "{{ data[k] }}"{% if not loop.last %}{{ delimiter }}{% endif %}
          {% else %}
          {{ data[k] }}{% if not loop.last %}{{ delimiter }}{% endif %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        delimiter: ','
        quote_list: [path]
```

Comment: I tried this, it managed to create the headers, but the values for each of the three users are all on the second row. So in total, the CSV file only has 2 rows instead of the 4 that you expected

Comment: This is what I got when I debug the template:
"msg": "FirstName,Alias Name,Code,Date of Submission,Description,path\nPeter,,#3091,14/5/2023,NIL,\"OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local\"Sam,,#3092,2/5/2023,NIL,\"OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local\"Judy,,#3093,10/5/2023,NIL,\"OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local\"\n"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I did not leave a blank line between the two {% endfor %}. May I know why is there no need to leave a blank line between {% for data in data_list %} and {% for k in _keys %}?

Comment: Because one newline '\n' between lines (created by the space) is enough. Test it. We should delete the comments here. Do not put code into the comment. It's hard to read.